# Add some bottom padding to code snippets

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, markdown, code-formatting

Currently it's impossible to see the bottom line of code snippets because the horizontal scroll bar is positioned over the top of them ([post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770846/perl-get-bst-london-time-or-any-other-time)):

[image: Sample image of problem]

Please could you add some bottom padding so that it's possible to view the last line of code snippets?

Unlike [Cannot dismiss scrollbar in code box, blocks view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321136/cannot-dismiss-scrollbar-in-code-box-blocks-view?noredirect=1&lq=1) which is a support question with a workaround answer, this is a feature request suggesting a clear action hence not a duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard done

Comment: @KodosJohnson awesome, thanks.

Comment: I understand the logic here that this is a chrome bug however justify having IE8 css fixes in the markup...

Comment: There’s now a larger padding: [Has the padding on code blocks been increased?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381254/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can’t fix Apple's bug, but as you note we CAN work around it - and now we have. Details here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381280/734487

Answer (score 5):

This will create unnecessary padding in other browsers.

Also, the comments on the answer in the other meta post that you linked to suggests that this is a Chrome bug and a bug report has been filed here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=914844