# What happened to code fences and Stack Snippets?

Tags: discussion, design, code-formatting, code

I just noticed that something weird happened today with code fences and Stack Snippets.

Examples:

```html
<h1>Hello World!<h1>
```

```
Hello World!
```

Seems like the boxes are bigger. What is the (unneeded?) space above, under and left the code?

I know this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), but is there a benefit it was designed like this? I (at least) found it confusing to follow in large script:

```js
var a = "a";
var b = "b";
var c = "c";

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [Has the padding on code blocks been increased?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381254/4642212). Also see [Add some bottom padding to code snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323533/289905).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was changed to address a long-standing issue with Macs' weird-ass "auto-hiding-and-then-reappearing-on-top-of-your-code" scrollbar feature.

More details in Ted's answer here: [Has the padding on code blocks been increased?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381254/has-the-padding-on-code-blocks-been-increased/381280#381280)